# BeagleBone Black SGX SDK missing EWSTest

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, beagleboneblack, powervr-sgx

I downloaded and installed the SGX SDK 5.01.01.01 on my BeagleBone Black without any issues.  I can run the demos and they work just fine.  My problem is I'm trying to write a simple C++ application to access the EWS functionality, like EWSOpenDisplay.  I was able to find the libews.so library in the debug folder only, NOT in the release folder.  I can use the library but when I do I get the error below:

> ./EWSTest: error while loading shared libraries: /libews.so
>
> : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So my question is, where can I find the EWSTest file?